# Differential Equation Question $(\frac{2x^3}{y}-4x^2\cdot e^{4y})dy-(2x^2lny-2x\cdot e^{4y}) dx$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find the solution for the following equation
$$(\frac{2x^3}{y}-4x^2\cdot e^{4y})dy-(2x^2lny-2x\cdot e^{4y}) dx$$
what I tried to do is, set

1. $P(x,y) = (2x^2lny-2x\cdot e^{4y})$
2. $Q(x,y)=(\frac{2x^3}{y}-4x^2\cdot e^{4y})$

$$\frac{dp}{dx}=\frac{2x^2}{y}-8xe^{4y},\frac{dq}{dy}=\frac{6x^2}{y}-8xe^{4y}$$
any suggestions how to continue?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The equation is in the form $P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy=0$ and it has an integrating factor $$\mu(x)=\frac{1}{x^4}.$$ This factor has been found by solving $\frac{P_y-Q_x}{Q}=-\frac{4}{x}=\frac{d\mu}{\mu}$, where $P(x,y) = -2x^2lny+2xe^{4y}$ and $Q(x,y)=\frac{2x^3}{y}-4x^2 e^{4y}$. Here is the calculation: $$P_y=-2x^2y^{-1}+8xe^{4y}$$ and $$Q_x=6x^2y^{-1}-8xe^{4y}$$$$\Rightarrow P_y-Qx= -8x^2y^{-1}+16xe^{4y}=-8(x^2y^{-1}-2xe^{4y})\Rightarrow$$$$\frac{P_y-Q_x}{Q}=\frac{-8(x^2y^{-1}-2xe^{4y})}{2x(x^2y^{-1}-2x e^{4y})}=-\frac{4}{x}.$$ Thus $$\mu(x)=e^{-\int\frac{4}{x}dx}=\frac{1}{x^4}.$$

Comment: this is what I did, but didnt get the integrating factor, you can show me the way? thanks.